# Flutter | Chart Pie | Information from database

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I want to create a data chart from a database. But when I run it returns error null.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OVYF.png)

```
List<charts.Series<Transactions, String>> _series(BuildContext context) {

    final myTransaction = Provider.of<Transaction>(context).myTransaction;

    List<Transactions> data = List<Transactions>();
    data.add(Transactions(category: myTransaction.category, amount: myTransaction.amount, color: myTransaction.color));

    return [
      charts.Series<Transactions, String>(
          id: 'Transactions',
          domainFn: (Transactions transactions, _) => transactions.category,
          measureFn: (Transactions transactions, _) => transactions.amount,
          labelAccessorFn: (Transactions transactions, _) => '\$${transactions.amount}',
          colorFn: (Transactions transactions, _) =>
              charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(
                  HexColor.fromHex(transactions.color)),
          data: data
      )
    ];
  }
```

Comment: where you initialize `transactions`?

Comment: new code that I placed

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `myTransaction` in `Transaction` class.

```
 Transactions myTransaction = Transaction() ;
```